# Sitecore Dependency Injection - register two abstractions to same singleton instance of an implementation

Tags: dependency-injection

When using the native Sitecore Dependency Injection I have 2 abstrations:

- `IService`
- `IExtendedService`

I want them both to be registered to same singleton instance of a `ServiceImplementation`

How do I register the implementation with my IoC Container to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Same instance for multiple services

I believe this can only be achieved with code registration:

```
var implementation = new ServiceImplementation();

serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IService>(provider => implementation);
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IExtendedService>(provider => implementation);
```

In case `ServiceImplementation` has its own dependencies, you will need to instantiate it from the container as well. Here's a trick you can use:

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IService, ServiceImplementation>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IExtendedService>(
    provider => (ServiceImplementation)provider.GetService(typeof(IService)));
```

---

Below you can find more general details that I typed in before fully understanding the question :)

### XML registration

If you're using XML registration, just add a .config patch file with the following contents:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <services>
      <register
        serviceType="[Namespace].IService, [Assembly]"
        implementationType="[Namespace].ServiceImplementation, [Assembly]"
        lifetime="Singleton" />
      <register
        serviceType="[Namespace].IExtendedService, [Assembly]"
        implementationType="[Namespace].ServiceImplementation, [Assembly]"
        lifetime="Singleton" />
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

### Code registration

You should use Sitecore [**configurators**](http://kamsar.net/index.php/2016/08/Dependency-Injection-in-Sitecore-8-2/#Configurators) to register dependencies from code.

There are many available registration methods. Here's an example with a singleton dependency:

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IExtendedService, ServiceImplementation>;
```

A transient example:

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IService>(provider => new ServiceImplementation());
```

To see the complete list of available registration methods, decompile the class `ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions` in the assembly `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`. The main variations are:

- `AddTransient<...>(...)`
- `AddScoped<...>(...)`
- `AddSingleton<...>(...)`
- `Add(Type, Type, ServiceLifetime)`
- `Add(Type, Func<IServiceProvider, object>, ServiceLifetime)`

### Dependency lifetime

Regardles of which registration method you choose, remember to specify an appropriate lifetime scope. The supported options are:

- `Singleton`
- `Scoped`
- `Transient`

### Further reading

- https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection.html
- http://kamsar.net/index.php/2016/08/Dependency-Injection-in-Sitecore-8-2/

Comment: Good answer, that helped a lot (especially if serviceImplementation has it's own dependencies). One hint/remark: GetService also has a generic interface which to me looks nicer :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to register the two interfaces to the same singleton instance implementation, but only in code, not in config.

```
ServiceImplementation impl = new ServiceImplementation();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IService>(provider => impl);
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IExtendedService>(provider => impl);
```

This kinda sucks because you're newing up the singleton instance here....but it'll work.

I originally attempted this in config, however this **DOES NOT WORK**.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <services>
            <register 
                serviceType="MyContracts.MyNamespace.IService, MyContracts" 
                implementationType="MyProject.MyNamespace.ServiceImplementation, MyProject" 
                lifetime="Transient" />
            <register serviceType="MyContracts.MyNamespace.IExtendedService, MyContracts" 
                implementationType="MyProject.MyNamespace.ServiceImplementation, MyProject" 
                lifetime="Transient" />
        </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are we sure that these will give same instance?

I will rephrase:

I want to register a singleton.
The implementation class implements 2 interfaces:

IService, IExtendedService

So if I get 2 instances:

var service = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IService>();
var extendedService = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IExtendedService>();

I want them to be same instance.

Comment: Updated the answer. Yeah, after testing, doing it in config doesn't work. You can follow the way I did it above, which isn't great and is a side effect of the .NET Core conforming container problem.

Comment: If you make the factory registration for one interface ServiceLocate the other interface, you should get a single instance for both interfaces.

Comment: this worked:
`serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IService, ServiceImplementation>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IExtendedService>(
    provider => (ServiceImplementation)provider.GetService(typeof(IService)));`